# What's the purpose of StartupProjectName parameter in Add-Migration in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

As I understand what `Add-Migration` is doing, it's just compares the current model of code with the model of last applied migration (which has the entire model in its resx file)

For the description of StartupProjectName paramter it says:

> **-StartUpProjectName**
>
> Specifies the configuration file to use for **named connection strings**.
>   If omitted, the specified project’s configuration file is used.

If each migration has a snapshot of whole model, then there would no need to have a database, since the current model and that snapshot are totally comparable.

So why is this parameter provided in **Add-Migration** command to specify a connection string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that parameter you can specify the project which contains your connection string (in app.config e.g.).

You can have your migrations in a seperate project (which doesn't contain the connection string).

Comment: My question is why Add-Migration would need connection string. As I know it won't need a database in any phase of its job.

Comment: It does need a connection, the migration history is retrieved via the __MigrationHistory table.This table stores the information about the migrations.

Comment: But Add-Migration is not going to update the database. So why would it need the database. All it's going to do is find the difference between current model with last snapshot.

Comment: And where does it get its snapshot from?

Comment: In the following link it says that each migration has a full snapshot in its resx file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add-Migration does not require "-StartUpProjectName" since you can choose the "default project" from the drop list above the package-manager console.
You can override the "default project" value from the drop list by using the parameter "-StartUpProjectName"