# Ways to manage configuration in project with multiple tiers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

ASP.NET Core project template comes with `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` and it is added by default in [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L171).

Because the project with `DbContext` is separate from my ASP.NET Core project (`MyProject.Data`) I am required to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` for my context in order for commands like `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` to work. I don't want to hardcode my connection string for my `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` but re-use the config in both projects.

I have few solutions for it but I want to know what's the most reasonable based on your experiences and opinions.

- Implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in my ASP.NET Core (UI layer) project.
- Implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in my `MyProject.Data` project, and move `appsettings.json` to some root directory, or `configuration` (located at root) directory shared between projects.
- Create separate configuration file for database like `database.json` put it alongside my `.sln` file.

How should I share this?

EDIT:

There's similar question and answer here: [ConnectionString from appsettings.json in Data Tier with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356990/connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-data-tier-with-entity-framework-core) but it doesn't answer my question. It doesn't say anything about data tier at all. I don't want to re-use logic for adding db context. **I want to re-use connection string in two projects** to avoid duplicating connection strings.

Comment: Not a similar/same concept to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356990/connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-data-tier-with-entity-framework-core?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConnectionString from appsettings.json in Data Tier with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356990/connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-data-tier-with-entity-framework-core)

Comment: The answer in mentioned question doesn't say anything about storing `json` settings and is completely unrelated.

Comment: That's what the startup file is for and the extension method from the data layer in the link, you would then use configuration in your startup - your startup should be the point of entry to the system and as such that configures dependant projects.
You may need to explain your question more otherwise for the benefit of others.

Comment: @danrichardson but design time factory must be in my Web/ASP.NET Core project because otherwise, I have to set the path to my configuration in my Data project. I'm just saying that the problem is only with migration tools and commands like `Update-Database` and `Add-Migration` which require design-time factory.

Comment: You should still be able to run those commands through the console with `-startupprojectname` though I would assume in order to use the appsettings.json file in the UI project - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267974/whats-the-purpose-of-startupprojectname-parameter-in-add-migration-in-ef

Comment: @danrichardson it's tedious to use `-startupprojectname` all the time

Comment: @Konrad you can create a shell or batch script for it

Comment: Then similar to the other post refactor the extension to depend on configuration to extract connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While is it usually advised to have configuration in a central location, there is nothing restricting individual projects from managing their own configuration.

In the following example the connection string information is stored in an external *datasettings.json* file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "connection string here"
  }
}
```

A simple example of a self contained setup extension for the layer could look like

```
public static class MyServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyDataLayer(this IServiceCollection services, string name = "DefaultConnection") {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("datasettings.json"); //<<< just an example

        var connectionStringConfig = builder.Build();

        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
                options
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionStringConfig.GetConnectionString(name))
            );
         return services;
    }
}
```

And added in *Startup*

```
using my.data.layer;

//...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddMyDataLayer();

    //...
}
```

The data layer in this case manages its own configuration. Its settings file external to the application settings.

There is room for expansion as additional options could be managed locally as well and works well for drop-in turn key plug-in solutions for example.

The module nature of [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) allows for such flexibilities.

Answer (score 0):

My approach/opinion to this topic:

Use a connection String in every top layer application using your DbContext like API/Backend/Frontend because they could run on different servers. So they should have their own settings file.

To handle Migrations from the Library without connection string you can use the following approach:

`cd /projectWithContextImpl`

`dotnet ef -s "../projectWithConnString/" migrations list -c NameOfContext`

I hope this somewhat answers your question.